# Do we need to install microsoft office on server pc, if we are using EPPlus library?

Tags: asp.net

I want to export excel files from my web application, I EPPlus library for it. I dont want to install ms office on my server pc. Does this library require msoffice installed?
Please suggest..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

According to [the project's FAQ](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ): no.

> **What are the requirements for this library?**
>
> .Net Framwork 3.5 or higher. This library utilize the System.IO.Packaging 
>   namespace.

A general advice: Please do some research before posting questions on SO.